# How to break an array of objects into 2 arrays, using Underscore/LoDash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I have an array of objects:

```
var arr = [
  {field1: value, field2: value, field3: value, field4: value},
  {field1: value, field2: value, field3: value, field4: value},
  {field1: value, field2: value, field3: value, field4: value}
];
```

I need to break it into 2 arrays of objects: one containing objects that have only field1 and field 3, and one containing objects that have all the rest. I'm trying to use Underscore (well, actually LoDash - but they're the same) and so far, all I got is:

```
var arr1 = [], arr2 = [];
_.forEach(arr, function(line) {
    arr1.push(_.pick(line, ['field1', 'field3']));
    arr2.push(_.omit(line, ['field1', 'field3']));
});
```

While this code works it strikes me as very inefficient. I'm sure I'm missing an Underscore function that can make my life easier, my code more readable, and my program more efficient.

Comment: What do you mean when you say inefficient?

Comment: Seems like many internal iterations occur. Since both US and LD say they have a better iteration implementation, I was wondering if there's a way to take advantage of it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is easier to read or more efficient then what you have written. But it does use underscore.

```
var arrs = _.reduce(arr, function(memo, item){

  var firstArr = _.chain(_.first(memo)).push(_.pick(item, ['field1', 'field3'])).value();
  var secondArr = _.chain(_.last(memo)).push(_.omit(item, ['field1', 'field3'])).value();

  return [ firstArr, secondArr ];

}, [[], []]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = [
  {field1: value, field2: value, field3: value, field4: value},
  {field1: value, field2: value, field3: value, field4: value},
  {field1: value, field2: value, field3: value, field4: value}
];

/* Generic function to get key-value pair form array of object.
 input >> is array of object.
 keys >> array of string keys.
 isNotRequired >> boolean flag whether output contains the keys which are provided or the keys except which are provided.
*/

function getKeyValues(input, keys, isNotRequired) {
    if (!keys || !keys.length) {
        return input;
    }
    return _.reduce(input, function(output, values) {
        output.push(_.reduce(values, function(object, value, key) {
            if (!isNotRequired) {
                if (keys.indexOf(key) > -1) {
                    object[key] = value;
                }
            } else if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                object[key] = value;
            }
            return object;
        }, {}));
        return output;
    }, []);
}
```

//In your example hot to use the function:

```
var FirstArrayWithField1AndField2 = getKeyValues(input,['field1','field2']);
var SecondArrayWithoutField1AndField2 = getKeyValues(input,['field1','field2'],true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Underscore uses native `Array.prototype.forEach` method for its alias `_.forEach`. If  it is not present somehow then it would define its own `forEach` iterator using the simple for loop. Apparently the performance of native `forEach` [isn't that great](http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/2) to the simple for loop. That's because the native `forEach` performs a [lot of checks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) while iterating.

I can only suggest that you re define `_.forEach` method like this -

```
_.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) {
    if (obj == null) return;
    if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
        for (var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (iterator.call(context, obj[i], i, obj) === breaker) return;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrs = _.groupBy(arr, function(obj) {
    return 'field1' in obj && 'field3' in obj;
});
```

This will return an object with properties named `true` and `false`.

Comment: While this appears to solve the problem described in the question, it is not equivalent to the code within it. I think the OP has to clarify his intend.

Comment: I need to end up with 2 arrays as specified. All fields do exist in the original array, so this code does not help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i ,target,length = arr.length, arr1 = [], arr2 = [];
for(i = 0; i< length;i++){
  target = arr[i];
  arr1.push({
    field1: target.field1, 
    field3: target.field3:
  });
  arr2.push({
    field2: target.field2, 
    field4: target.field4:
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myarr = 
[
      {'field1': 'val01', 'field2': 'val02', 'field3': 'val03', 'field4': 'val04'},
      {'field1': 'val11', 'field2': 'val12', 'field3': 'val13', 'field4': 'val14'},
      {'field1': 'val21', 'field2': 'val22', 'field3': 'val23', 'field4': 'val24'},
      {'field1': 'val31', 'field2': 'val32', 'field3': 'val33', 'field4': 'val34'}
];

var fields13 = [];
var fields24 = [];


_.each(myarr, function(myobj) 
{ 
      fields13.push(myobj.field1);
      fields24.push(myobj.field2);
      fields13.push(myobj.field3);
      fields24.push(myobj.field4);
});

console.log(fields13);
console.log(fields24);
```